# Pre-commit hook not working in Github Desktop

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, github-desktop

I set up a `pre-commit` hook on my **Mac** to avoid committing with rubocop errors:

```
echo -e "[RUBOCOP] Init..."

RUBOCOP=`bundle exec rubocop`

if [ "grep $RUBOCOP 'no offenses detected' -c" == "1" ]; then
    echo -e "[RUBOCOP]  approved."
    exit 0
else
    echo -e "[RUBOCOP] ✋ \n"
    bundle exec rubocop
    exit 1
fi
```

It works just fine in the terminal, but it messes up my Github Desktop app - throwing this error:

> [RUBOCOP] Init...
>
> /Users/PATH_TO_PROJECT/.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 3: bundle: command not found
>
> [RUBOCOP] ✋
>
> /Users/PATH_TO_PROJECT/.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 10: bundle: command not found

I searched, but found nothing related, I also do understand what the error means. I just can't figure out how to enable the `bundle` or `rubocop` command for Github Desktop.

Comment: Try the full path of `bundle` in `bundle exec rubocop` at line 3 and 10.

Comment: that worked out! Thank you